# Adding a product component to basket with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, components, react-hooks

The click on the button of any product card must add a component "AddedProduct" into the component "Basket". Depending on chosen product, the component "AddedProduct" must take the right data about product from the array of objects "productsDataArray". I've tried such approach: initial state of basket content is empty array. The changing state must contain the component "AddedProduct" with the right data.  But my code dosn't add the component. I'm just studying reactjs, so I can't understand how to write correctly the function "clickBtn" for adding products to basket. Help me, please. (the code is without 'imports' here):

```
 export const MainPage = props => {                 {/* parent component with product cards*/} 
     const [basketContent, changeBasketContent] = useState([]);  

     const updateContent = (product) => {
         const addedItems = productsDataArray.filter(item => item.id == 
                 product.id);
              return (
                 <div>                      
                    <AddedProducts productData = {product} />                                
                 </div>                                           
              );                   
         changeBasketContent([addedItems]);         
     };

     const clickBtn = (e) => {     
        updateContent(e.target);
     };  

           return ( 
             <div> 
                <div id = 'productSection'> 
                   {productsDataArray.map(item => {
                     return (
                      <div key = {item.id}>
                         ProductCard productData = {item}
                         clickBtn = {clickBtn}                                        
                       />             
                      </div>  
                       );
                     }                 
                  )}
                </div>
                <Basket/>
           </div> 
        );
     };

 export const ProductCard = props => {     
    const {productData, clickBtn} = props;           
      return (  
          <div id = 'productCard' style = {{width: '300px'}}>
               <img src = {productData.photo} alt = {productData.name} height 
                     = "200" />
               <div>
                  <h6>{productData.name}</h6>
                  <div>    
                     <p>Price: {productData.price}</p>
                     <button type = 'button' onClick = {clickBtn}>                               
                            Add to basket
                     </button>              
                  </div>                   
               </div>
             </div>        
             
           );
  };        
       
export const Basket = props => {        
const {basketContent} = props;    
    
    return (  
        <section id = 'basket-bloc'>       
            <div id = "basket-main">        
                 {basketContent}       
            </div>         
        </section>
      );
}; 

export const AddedProduct = props => {
   const {productData} = props;    
   return (  
     <div id = 'addedProduct'>         
        <div id = 'product-img-small' className = 'basketItem'>
            <img src = {productData.photo} width = '50'
                 alt = {productData.name} />
        </div>
         <div id ='product-name' className = 'basketItem'>
            <p>{productData.name}</p>         
        </div> 
     </div> 
     );
 };                                                  
    
 export const productsDataArray = [
   { 
      id : 1.1, 
      name: "Title1",
      price: "10$",
      photo: img1     
   },
   { 
     id : 1.2,  
     name: "Title2",
     price: "20$",
     photo: img2     
   },
   { 
     id : 1.3,  
     name: "Title3",
     price: "30$",
     photo: img3     
   },
   { 
    id : 1.4,   
    name: "Title4",
    price: "25$",
    photo: img4    
   }          
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<button type = 'button' onClick = {clickBtn}>
    Add to basket
</button>
```

with

```
<button type='button' onClick={(e) => clickBtn(e)}>
    Add to basket
</button>
```

We have to do this because you we have only one handler for multiple items.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't change anything, I think sth wrong with functions 'updateContent' and 'clickBtn'

Comment: You are using catData in the MainPage component, but I can't seem to find it declared anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, it's a lapsus, in real code is writen productData.